# TouchableNativeFeedback onpress Not Working ReactNative

Tags: reactjs, react-native, touchableopacity

I imported {TouchableNativeFeedback} from 'react-native'

In the render() function I am trying to use TouchableNativeFeedback; however, the function onpress is triggered only when the app reloads. When pressing the TouchableNativeFeedback the onpress function is not triggered. What's the problem? How can I have a TouchableNativeFeedback with onpress function working?

```
<View style={style.gameBody}>
                    {this.state.isMystery=='false'?
                        <View style={style.drinkBody}>


                            {/* BEER LOGO AND BEER COUNTER */}
                            <TouchableNativeFeedback style={style.beerText} onpress={console.log('this got preseed')}>

                                <View style={style.beerText}>

                                    <Image
                                    source={require('../img/beer.png')}
                                    style={style.beerStyling}/>
                                    <Feather style={style.beerCountXStyle} name='x'/>
                                    <Text style={style.beerDrinkCounterStyle}>
                                        {this.state.round1Drink[this.state.gameNum]}
                                    </Text>

                                    {/* Line Stlye */}
                                    <Image
                                    source={require('../img/line.png')}
                                    style={style.lineStyle}/>
                                </View>
                            </TouchableNativeFeedback>


                            {/* BEER TEXT/CARD SCREEN HERE */}
                            <Text style={style.drinkText} 
                            onPress={() => RandomChooseRound1()} // add this.startAnimation here
                            >        
                            </Text>
                        </View>
                        : null
                    }
```

The onpress function in  Works; however, the onpress function doesn not work for

```
<Text style={style.drinkText} onPress={() => RandomChooseRound1()}
```

When pressing on the text, the onpress function works.
Please Help! Thank you!

Comment: are you using a class component or functional? and can you share your randomchoosefunction?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing a 'this'.

```
<Text style={style.drinkText} onPress={() => this.RandomChooseRound1()}>
```